# VS Code: C/C++ Extension: Ignoring includePath, Linking to Wrong Header Files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include-path

I am using the [C/C++ Extension for VS Code to write OpenCV code on Ubuntu 18.04](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux). I have configured my `c_cpp_properties.json` file like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I want it to reference the OpenCV header files from the location `/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/`; but every time I 'Go to Definition' of any of the OpenCV code I've written, it takes me to header files from the folder `/usr/include/opencv2/`, which contains code from an older OpenCV version. Because of this, I am unable to use certain newer features that I require.

I don't want to delete the header files in the second location, as these were most likely installed when I installed ROS, and I don't want to break the ROS installation. I just want VS Code to reference the header files from the location I've specified, *like it's supposed to*.

Comment: Try to reset c++ intellisense database. Ctrl + Ship + P => C++: Reset intellisense

Comment: Also it is possible that ```/usr/include``` is a default include path for compiler.

Comment: @Roy2511 I tried resetting...didn't work.

Comment: @Roy2511 How do I see the default include paths for my compiler. Also, are you sure that  the default include paths for the compiler carry over to VS Code Intellisense?

Comment: I does, atleast for Windows. For instance, I don't have to specify the location for ```windows.h``` in ```includePath``` if I include it in a project (provided I am using MSVC compiler).

Comment: If you're building with cmake then I'd recommend the cmake extension, it automatically configures intellisense based on your build settings. You presumably are including `#include <opencv2/...`, your include path should probably be `/usr/local/include/opencv4/**`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Hey, thanks! That was exactly the problem...very foolish of me. I changed the include path to `/usr/local/include/opencv4/**` and everything worked!